# python classes dynamic object instantiation/creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instantiation, python-decorators

I want to create some users just to populate my database, so using decorators I created a method inside a class for it. I returned the results into a list and used the information without a problem. But after a while I thought that once I was working with classes wouldn't be dumb to use lists? I feel that I am kind of moving backwards since, at least in my understanding, it might be possible to access those values directly.. But the truth is I struggled on attempting to instantiate dynamically and access those instances. So, how could I do that properly? Here is the code I wrote in the first attempt:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, user_name, password, email, i=0):
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.password = password
        self.email = email

    @classmethod
    def from_generate(cls, amount):
        user_name = 'user' + str(amount)
        password = 'password000.' + str(amount)
        email = 'user' + str(amount) + "@whatever.com"
        return cls(user_name, password, email)
```

in another file:

```
def user_generator(user_qty=0):
    user_list = []

    for i in range(1, user_qty + 1):

        # call the class method to generate users
        instance = User.from_generate(i)
        user_list.append(instance)
    return(user_list)



users = user_generator(5)

if __name__ == "__user_generator__":
    user_generator()
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Your code is also not idiomatic Python. There is no reason for you `from_generate()` function to exist. Just change the `__init__()` method to accept just a user ID and synthesize the instance values directly. You then use it as `instance = User(i)`. Your approach is very unusual and, frankly, weird.

Comment: I got the same feeling about the weirdness.. But I couldn't say why. Although, at some point, I could use the __init__() method to create users via inputs from users, I am not doing this at this point. So your approach makes much more sense. Thank you!